# connect to different database without service builder in liferay

Tags: spring, liferay, spring-jdbc

I want to connect to different database (other than liferay default database) without service builder. Also I want to use spring jdbc template to fetch the data from database.

Comment: If that's what you truly want - go ahead and do it. It's nice to let us know, but as you didn't include any question, I'm not sure about the motivation for your post (?)

Comment: Just create portlet, add spring dependencies and create your dao. I